# Azure website hanging; killing request and refreshes fixes issue

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cloudflare

I have something very weird happening on my Azure website just today. I have not released any new code lately.

Approximately every 3rd to 5th page that I request on the site, it will sit there and hang, and eventually get an Error 524 (presented by CloudFlare). It tells me that my server or database may be overloaded. Checking Azure everything's running fine at less than 10% consumption.

The weird thing is, on the page requests that hang, if I kill the request (clicking the X where the refresh button normally is on Google Chrome), then retry the page, it returns everything immediately.

This morning when I first noticed, I thought it might have been Azure, so I checked the Azure status page, and sure enough, my region was having latency problems.

But, the problems, according to Azure, have apparently been resolved, yet I'm still receiving these same symptoms/errors.

Checking my error table just shows the db calls that are timing out while this is occurring, no patterns that I could recognize.

I've checked App Insights as well, checking the pages before and after and nothing is jumping out at me. I have another user over in the eastern United States and he said he hasn't noticed anything and all is working great.

I don't know what else to be checking here. This is consistently-inconsistent!

Here's the website to try:

[www.wrestlestat.com](https://www.wrestlestat.com)

This is really frustrating because both Azure and CloudFlare status pages say everything is working normally. This is still happnening for me, anywhere from 3 to 5 pages one will hang...

**EDIT/UPDATE** - 2 days after incident started it has magically fixed itself. I have no idea of anything done, and I released NO code changes to attempt a fix. I'm baffled.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, may be region issue for some service

Comment: How can you be certain it's not a cloudflare issue?

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess I can't, you're right, could definitely be on their end